# How to highlight the current line of a Text widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a simple GUI code editor in Python, and I want to have the line of text on which the cursor sits to be highlighted at all times.

Right now, my `TextEditor` class looks like:

```
class TextEditor:

   def __init__(self, container):
      self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(container)
      self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

      self.textbox = Text(container, height=40, undo=True, width=80,
                          font=tkFont.Font(family="Consolas", size=12))
      self.textbox.pack(side=LEFT)

      self.textbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
      self.scrollbar.config(command=self.textbox.yview)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing built in to tkinter that directly supports that. However, something that is good enough for most purposes would be to write a function that polls for the cursor position and updates the highlighting at regular intervals.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.tag_configure("current_line", background="#e9e9e9")
        self.text.tag_raise("sel", "current_line")

        self._highlight_current_line()

    def _highlight_current_line(self, interval=100):
        '''Updates the 'current line' highlighting every "interval" milliseconds'''
        if not self.text.winfo_exists():
            return
        self.text.tag_remove("current_line", "1.0", "end")
        self.text.tag_add("current_line", "insert linestart", "insert lineend+1c")
        self.after(interval, self._highlight_current_line, interval)

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Obviously, the longer the interval the more "lag" that will be introduced, and the shorter the interval the more CPU is used, but there's a pretty large sweet spot between the extremes where there's almost no perceptible lag, and an imperceptible bump in CPU usage.

There's another way to do it that doesn't involve polling and is absolutely foolproof. You can move the highlight to precisely when the insertion cursor actually moves, but it involves writing some embedded Tcl code to create a proxy of the actual tk widget that is hidden in the implementation of the Tkinter `Text` object.

Finally, a third way is to set up custom bindings for all of the possible events that modify the cursor location. While possible, it's difficult to get 100% right since you have to account for *all* events that modify the cursor position, as well as handle places in your code that that might move the cursor without using an event. Still, using bindings is a perfectly good solution, it just requires a bit more work.

Comment: Why would you poll? I just checked and I can bind to keypresses and mouse click events in a `Text`. Unless I'm missing something, it seems to me that that means you can bind to any user event that has the potential to move the cursor. As for programatic reasons your cursor might move - your code is responsible for doing it, so whenever that happens, just call the _highlight_current_line right afterwards.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: why poll? Mainly because it is a simple solution. Yes, you can bind to every even that moves the cursor, but do you know what all those events are? You can probably figure it out, but then you also need to remember to call your code whenever you programatically insert text. Polling is simple, effective, and almost foolproof.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely no need to poll [like Bryan Oakley says in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9720858/901641), nor do you need to embed Tcl code in your Python code. My solution is to just bind to the events which may end up moving the cursor, namely `<Key>` and `<Button-1>`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class CurrentHighlightedLineText(tk.Text):

    """Text widget with current line highlighted"""

    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tag_configure('currentLine', background='#e9e9e9')
        self.bind('<Key>', lambda _: self.highlightCurrentLine())
        self.bind('<Button-1>', lambda _: self.highlightCurrentLine())
        self.highlightCurrentLine(delay=0)

    def highlightCurrentLine(self, delay=10):

        def delayedHighlightCurrentLine():
            self.tag_remove('currentLine', 1.0, "end")
            self.tag_add('currentLine', 'insert linestart', 'insert lineend+1c')
        # This bound function is called before the cursor actually moves.
        # So delay checking the cursor position and moving the highlight 10 ms.

        self.after(delay, delayedHighlightCurrentLine)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    text = CurrentHighlightedLineText(root)
    text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a good illustration of why polling is as good, if not better solution. There are things that can cause the cursor to move that your code doesn't handle (for example, pasting code with a right click or from a menu). That doesn't mean your code can't handle them, just that it's difficult to account for all edge cases. Also, you can solve this "delay" problem more elegantly by adding a special bind tag after the class binding, so that your binding happens after the cursor moves rather than before.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I'd imagine programmatically modifying the text can probably be handled through a combination of overriding any methods defined by `tk.Text` and maybe handling some magic methods, like `__setitem__`. I definitely wouldn't suggest polling instead of this. If you have an inarguable improvement over using the delay, please edit my answer to handle that. I've never managed to get special bind tags to work in Tkinter, but maybe I've just been using them wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about how to handle programmatic modification of the widget. The point being, your solution starts to become very complex. I'm not saying it's a bad solution, just that it's a surprisingly complex one.

Comment: Per your request, I've updated your answer to use bindtags so that the delay is not required.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Hi Bryan, I tried the code you edited into my answer but it didn't work for me. Inserting that code seems to have removed the ability to type at all. By inserting a `print` statement into the `highlightCurrentLine` function, I can see that the function was getting called, but text was never actually getting inserted. I rolled back to before the edit. I'm using Python 2.7.6 and Tcl 8.5 if that makes any difference.

Comment: That seems very odd. Did you copy and paste the exact code from the answer, or did you re-type it? I tested the exact code (except for the import statement) python 2.7.6.

Comment: You can use <ButtonRelease-1> instead <Button-1> and there is no need to make a delay

Comment: @VadimZin4uk - Ooohhh, that sounds like a good idea. I'll have to try that later.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Bryan Oakley's answer: Simply highlighting the current line becomes a pain when you want to select some text that includes part, but not all, of the current line, because the part of the current line that is selected is colored using the current-line color, not the selected-text color, so it's harder to see at a glance what part of the current line is selected.

So I modified Bryan's example code to NOT highlight the current line if any text is selected:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.tag_configure("current_line", background="#e9e9e9")
        self._highlight_current_line()

    def _highlight_current_line(self, interval=100):
        '''Rehighlights the 'current line' every "interval" milliseconds'''
        self.text.tag_remove("current_line", 1.0, "end")

        # If text is selected, DON'T highlight the current line.
        try:
            text = self.text.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)
        except tk.TclError:
            self.text.tag_add("current_line",
                                "insert linestart", "insert lineend+1c")

        self.after(interval, self._highlight_current_line)

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps somebody.